# What kind of headers and parameters does a browser set for SSO with Kerberos?

Tags: http, single-sign-on, kerberos

I would like to know what mandatory HTTP headers and parameters are set by the browser when negotiating a Kerberos SSO connection?

Please advise and many thanks in advance!

Comment: The standard is SPNEGO. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4559

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog: Would you mind kindly showing an actual example, please? I've read the RFC.

Comment: Try this command `curl --negotiate -u: https://site.spengo.com/private --verbose` Of course replacing the url with one that you know you can access using SPNEGO